# AngularJS: How to get form validation error value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I have a simple form like this using AngularJS 1.2 RC2 and bootstrap for css:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form" novalidate>
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-ng-minlength="3">
        <span class="help-block" data-ng-show="form.name.$error.minlength">Minimum length: {{???}}</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to show the value of data-ng-minlength for a specified form field instead of {{????}} in the above code.

I tried with "form.name.$error.minlength" or "form.name.$error.minlength.value" but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`form.name.$error.minlength` is not a boolean its a number, `ng-show` needs a boolean value.

Maybe something like this

```
data-ng-show="form.name.$error.minlength < 3"
```